# How to bulk save an array of objects in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have looked a long time and not found an answer. The Node.JS MongoDB driver docs say you can do bulk inserts using insert(docs) which is good and works well.

I now have a collection with over 4,000,000 items, and I need to add a new field to all of them. Usually mongodb can only write 1 transaction per 100ms, which means I would be waiting for days to update all those items. How can I do a "bulk save/update" to update them all at once? update() and save() seem to only work on a single object.

psuedo-code:

```
var stuffToSave = [];
db.collection('blah').find({}, function(err, stuff) {
    stuff.toArray().forEach(function(item)) {
        item.newField = someComplexCalculationInvolvingALookup();
        stuffToSave.push(item);
    }
}
db.saveButNotSuperSlow(stuffToSave);
```

Sure, I'll need to put some limit on doing something like 10,000 at once to not try do all 4 million at once, but i think you get the point.

Comment: Plenty of ways. Share some code, even bad. The driver in recent versions supports bulk operations on updates and other operations. Your "stats" are also relative to your own implementation. Not a "hard" number that is consistent everywhere.

Comment: In the first part you talk about insert. In the second part you suggest you need to do a update, which one is it? insert = new document, update = alter existing document(s)

Comment: I was merely pointing out that I wanted the same functionality offered in insert, in the save() api. I'll update with some pseudo-code.

Comment: Your comment doesn't really say anything, so theres not much there to misunderstand. Do you understand amortized writes? This is what I was referring to with my "hard number". What don't you understand about my update? Its not a complex task: 1. query for all objects. 2. update a new field on all objects. 3. save all objects.  I can't post real code because my employer wont allow such a thing. Point is, let me know if you are following so far, insert() supports being passed an array of documents for a reason. Is there an equivalent for save()?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB allows you to update many documents that match a specific query using a single `db.collection.update(query, update, options)` call, see the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).  For example,

```
db.blah.update(
   { },
   {
      $set: { newField: someComplexValue }
   },
   { 
      multi: true
   }
)
```

The `multi` option allows the command to update all documents that match the query criteria.  Note that the exact same thing applies when using the Node.JS driver, see [that documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#update).

If you're performing many *different* updates on a collection, you can wrap them all in a `Bulk()` builder to avoid some of the overhead of sending multiple updates to the database.